# How to check all values present in the column 'pincode'?

Tags: php, mysql

This code only reads the first value present in the column. If the value posted in the html form matches the first value, it inserts into the database. But I want to check all the values in the column and then take the respective actions.

For example, if i give input for 'ppincode' and 'dpincode' as 400001, it accepts. but if i gave 400002, 400003,..... it displays the alert even if those value are present in the database

DATABASE:
pincode <== column_name
400001  <== value
400002
400003
400004
...

also i tried this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM pincodes";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$pincodearray = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $pincodearray[] = $row;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to store the pincode value in an array and loop through the array to check for each value and then insert into DB if it matches.

Comment: First check if it exists: `SELECT id WHERE pincode=ppincode OR pincode=dpincode`. If the query returns no value, the pincode does not exist.

Comment: i tried the one above too but this time, its not even accepting the first value

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well - you want to compare value from POST request with all retrieved records saved in DB and if it matches - perform action.
If so, I would recommend using for(each) loop. Example:

```
if( !empty($row){
    foreach( $row as $key ){ 
        if($key['pincode'] == $ppincode && $key['pincode'] == $dpincode){
            // your action goes here
        }
    }
}
```

Additional tip: use prepared statements :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE ppincode=ppincode AND bpincode=bpincode
```

if this return 0 then insert or else show alert.